# Can't start AVD Manager or SDK Manager from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I installed Visual Studio Professional with Xamarin, but **without** Android SDK and Android NDK. Then I downloaded SDK and NDK separately, unzipped them and set their location in Visual Studio Options. I am able to create and run Android Apps and everything works fine. Except I can't launch either SDK Manager or AVD Manager from Visual Studio. When I click corresponding buttons nothing happens. Android SDK folder doesn't contain exe files of AVD and SDK Managers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because as of `Android SDK Tools 26.0.1`, Google has officially deprecated the SDK and AVD Manager GUI tools. They have replaced these tools with their CLI(Command Line Interface) tools. If you need more details about this, you can read up on them here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54521

**Note:** Xamarin is currently working on GUI tooling to replace this within the IDE.

Comment: But my builds tool version is 25.0.2

Comment: Build-tools != SDK tools.

Comment: I get it. Exe files shouldn't exist. I looked at my home PC there were no exe files. However, it was possible to start AVD Manager and SDK Manager from both Visual Studio and Android Studio. But in my work PC I can start from Android Studio, but not from Visual Studio. When I press corressponding toolbar buttons nothing happens.

Comment: Yes exactly. Upgrading to SDK tools 26.0.1 deprecated those exe and Android.bat. You can work around this by redownloading the SDK and not updating it.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the answers already given here, the issue of AVD Manager not opening in Visual Studio (nothing happens after clicking) can also be due to the settings folder missing in your system.

To fix this:

- Open CMD - Navigate by typing `cd C:\Users\your_username\`
- Create a new folder by the name `.android` by typing `mkdir .android`
- Now `cd .android` and create a new folder there - `mkdir avd`
- Restart Visual Studio

[Credits](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289633/android-device-manager-not-starting-if-settings-fo.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Jon has said

> Google has officially deprecated the SDK and AVD Manager GUI tools for
>   Android SDK Tools 26.0.1

I recommend you Installing the android studio and take advantage of its AVD manager. What I am trying to say is you can use it ***as a SDK and AVD provider*** not as an IDE. I don't know if it is a wise solution but it definitely works! So Install android studio and launch the android virtual device manager and create/edit your desired emulator. You will see the modifications or new devices in VS's emulator drop-down if both your VS and Android studios refer to a same SDK.