# SDK Manager VS 2015 not showing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I just installed VS 2015 with Update 3. I am unable to start the android SDK manager from the following menu (see image)
[image]

Nothing happen when I click on "Android SDK Manager" and when I go to

Tool->Options>Xamarn->Android Settings, It shows that the necessary paths have been set as below

[image]

Please how do I make the Android SDK Manager come up. PS: I installed Android Studio earlier and the SDK and Emulator managers are working fine.

Comment: This issue can be caused due to the missing settings folder. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646829/5330419)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Android SDK Tools package version after 25.2.3, you have to install the Xamarin Android SDK Manager plugin for Visual Studio (available from the Visual Studio Marketplace).

I've found it on Xamarin site [Windows Installation - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/#Android_SDK_Manager).

Direct link to download from visual studio [Xamarin.AndroidSDKManager.msi](https://xamarin.gallery.vsassets.io/_apis/public/gallery/publisher/Xamarin/extension/XamarinAndroidSDKManager/0.2.0.0/assetbyname/262984/4/Xamarin.AndroidSDKManager.msi?redirect=true&install=true)